# How to display Text from the Parse Database in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making an app in Swift with Parse and I need to display text from one of my Parse Database classes, so in short I simply need to display some text from my Parse Database onto a Label. I am using swift, how would this be done? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you read the Parse documentation?

Comment: @Dancreek Yes but I can't find anything.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS

Comment: @Dancreek I know how to query I just need to know how to display it in a Label

Comment: eeeeeeh just google UILabel tutorial maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Make an outlet to reference your label. Create a query for Parse, and when it returns the data, set your label's text to the data.